Looking for a tool / technique to edit rasterised text and retain the style. Alternatively, how to accomplish such a text effect?
I'm working on a project, printing my own money: https://moneyfromthefuture.com (Money from the Future)
Previously just AI, now levelling up my skills and using Photoshop with generative fill.
I would like to replace these numbers with something more meaningful:

But it is not so obvious, it is not so easy to retain the style.
I can remove the existing letters, then make my own text and add a clipping mask but the effect is nowhere near as good.

Follow up question (based on the discussion in the comments): how to accomplish that cool green text effect?
How would you do it?
How to accomplish the desired result?
Current project
2024-05-29 UPDATE:
Heading to hacker festival https://www.emfcamp.org/ tomorrow morning, this is the best I could create given my very basic skills. When you add quality paper + holograms + stamp + UV it becomes something pretty WOW, even though my personal expectations reach much much higher.


Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You can't edit rasterized text.  You can fill over it, and retype it.  I'm not going to test if it's possible with Photoshop's generative fill, because Adobe often prevents things like this from being edited - and I suspect they may think this looks like an attempt to forge money or doctor an official document.  Security backgrounds exist for a reason, to make editing nearly impossible. I'm also not going to get involved in suggesting ways you could overcome this, when it could be used for potentially criminal purposes. Sorry about that.

I would imagine that scanners / printers / photoshop have banknote detection, there some magical dots that prevent it. From the context nad judging by the quality of the image it should be obvious that is is AI generated. Besides I'm not talking about removing the background = that is simple = generative AI does the job. I'm talking about edit rasterised text and retain the style. I like the artefacts and shades of AI generation, on my own I didn't figure out how to accomplish such an effect.

The best you can do is clean up the background by erasing the text (gen AI works for that) and recreate the text, editable, with effects and all, on top of that. There's no way to edit a raster text, because it's not text anymore, it's just pixels. As per my answer.

It is not easy to retain the style as per design (that is the entire point of the pattern).

gen AI works for that - YEAH, it's easy. It is not easy to retain the style as per design - I respectfully do not agree, it's easy, gen AI does exactly that. The difficulty for me is to find / create suitable text effect.

Yeah generate it without text, then do a image to image transform of that text with ai, should be easy with suitable style transfer model. But really just do progressive blur on your text

I love the new functionality of Photoshop... Previously I had one-off purchase of Elements 2018, then Elements 2021 (due to OS incompatibility) but now with AI... I may find a new way of earning some income so I better learn the tools!

You can't edit raster text; it's converted from editable vector text (independent from the background) into bitmap pixels (background and text are the same). What you can do:

create your own Guilloché background pattern or get an existing one (for example, here)
add text using the Text tool (do not rasterize it)
add effects to the text. Keep the text editable, do not rasterize it.
You could add more complex effects and filters if you convert your text layer to Smart Object. Your text stays editable inside the smart object.

I wouldn't use generative fill for this, you should not attempt to alter a security background as Billy Kerr mentions in comments.

A reasonable answer to a potentially dangerous question. I like it.

I agree, but mainly because I don't want Adobe to blacklist me. These are fake guilloche patterns. I don't think the op is trying to copy real money.

@Wolff sure, but that's exaclty why the fake guilloche works in this case.

"add effects to the text." - that couly be my another question, how to accomplish such an effect? I was actually hoping that there is a tool / AI / magic button / silver bullet allowing to edit rasterized text.

@MarsRobertson you're right, the effects are a different question of its own. AFAIK there's no magic button yet besides the PS style presets. Someone had to put some work to make these https://designshack.net/articles/inspiration/photoshop-text-effects/
